# Why does an automatic bluetooth connect fails after some time?

Tags: bluetooth

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask my question. If not, please let me know a better place to ask it.

The question: I have a phone with bluetooth and is connected to a car, so you can use the phone hands-free. And when entering the car with the phone and bluetooth activated, the connection is made automatically.

But after some time, this connection is not made any more automatically. You have to pair them again. As far as I know there has neither been a system upgrade on the phone nor a new app was installed.

I am not asking for a solution, but for the possible reasons why you have to re-pair the car with the phone after some time (happened already a couple of times, after some months or so). What could be the reason for that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be due to many things, without more information it is impossible to pin-point where the problem is coming from.

Some common problems might be:

1. **Charge up** the device you're trying to pair. Some devices have smart power management that may turn off Bluetooth if the battery level is too low. This may cause the connection to terminate unexpectedly.
2. **Clear the Bluetooth cache** (Android only). Sometimes apps will interfere with Bluetooth operation and clearing the cache can solve the problem. Go Settings > Backup and restart > Reset network settings.
3. Sometimes **pairing of another device** with your car's Bluetooth may lead to your original device being unpaired. Make sure that no one else is pairing their device with your car.

Source: [Here](https://www.techlicious.com/how-to/how-to-fix-bluetooth-pairing-problems/)